# Как реализовать запрос по данным требованиям?

Tags: sql

Входные данные - Дата

SQL Запрос: Подсчитать количество `ID`, у которых значение `Value` по последней дате больше нуля.

```
Recid (key) |   ID  |   Date   | Value
1           |   1   | 02.02.11 |   7
2           |   1   | 02.03.12 |   8
3           |   1   | 02.04.13 |   0
4           |   1   | 02.05.14 |   2
5           |   2   | 02.01.12 |   8
6           |   2   | 02.02.13 |   0
7           |   3   | 02.02.13 |   2
8           |   3   | 02.03.14 |   2
9           |   3   | 02.05.14 |   0
```

Ввели дату - 03.05.14: Результат `Count=1` (ID - 1)
Ввели дату - 03.05.13: Результат `Count=1` (ID - 3)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
select count(*)
from rec join (
  select max(`date`) d, id 
  from rec
  where 
    `date`<"2013-05-03 00:00:00"
  group by id
) drec on rec.id = drec.id and rec.`date` = drec.d
where 
  rec.value>0;
```

Внутренний запрос берет записи "по последней дате", внешний отсекает нули.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c173/15

Comment: Решение верное, а можно как то в этом запросе избавится от вложенного запроса, заменив на join или noteexist?

Comment: @Дмитрий Даже если такой вариант и существует, не думаю что чем-то будет отличаться по производительности или по компактности/очевидности кода. Btw, join присутствует, для not exists будет также вложенный запрос. Чем вас не устраивает вложенный запрос в ответе?

Comment: в той среде где я буду использовать не допустимо вложенность запросов.

Comment: @Дмитрий странное ограничение (о вашей среде неплохо было бы указать в вопросе). ну, вы можете выполнять только внутренний запрос, а подсчетом заниматься в среде. проблема тут в двойной агрегации, которую в плоский вопрос не развернуть, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table t
WHERE t.Date = "03.05.13"
      AND t.Value>0
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Изменил группировку по `Date` на группировку по `ID`. Я не совсем понимаю, что значит "по последней дате"?

Comment: Если так, то это будет количество строк а не количество айди. Я предполога что можно так: запрос в запросе - во внутренеем сортировка по ID что бы последняя запись оказывалась в верху, а потом смотреть если первая запись по ИД > 0 то слаживать если нет то смотреть следующий ИД

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 count(distinct id)
from some_table
where date <= @limit
group by date
order by date desc
```